# Limit some specific day in a week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have bunch of dates in my database, and now I want to use WHERE to limit a specific day in a week  for eg. the date I have rn is 2019-01-01 etc. and I only want to see Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday among those date.   How do I do that?

The code I showed below does not work    just as a reference what I'm doing rn

```
CREATE VIEW weekend_reservation AS
    SELECT CONCAT(last_name,',',first_name) AS "guest's name",
            CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date,"%W,%M %d,%Y")) AS 'check_in_date',
            CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(check_out_date,"%W,%M %d,%Y")) AS 'check_out_date'
    FROM guests JOIN reservations
        USING(guest_id)
    WHERE check_in_date BETWEEN 'Friday' AND 'Sunday'
    ORDER BY check_in_date,check_out_date,last_name,first_name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't do it just by changing the `SELECT` to have the day-of-the-week.

Instead:

```
CREATE VIEW weekend_reservation AS
    SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', g.last_name, g.first_name) AS "guest's name",
           DATE_FORMAT(r.check_in_date, '%W, %M %d,%Y')) AS check_in_date,
           DATE_FORMAT(r.check_out_date, '%W,%M %d,%Y')) AS check_out_date
    FROM guests g JOIN
         reservations r
         USING (guest_id)
    WHERE DAYOFWEEK(r.check_in_date) IN (6, 7, 1)
    ORDER BY check_in_date, check_out_date, last_name, first_name;
```

Notes:

- `CONCAT()` after the `DATE_FORMAT()` does nothing.
- The `DAYOFWEEK()` function returns days, with Sunday as 1 and Saturday as 7.
- You should qualify all column names (i.e. use table alias), especially when a query has more than one table reference.
- `CONCAT_WS()` is handy.  It handles `NULL` values better than `CONCAT()`.

Comment: Thats exactly what i need  Thanks a lot